# Build a string in a computed SQL column from specific characters from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, calculated-columns, string-concatenation

I do not know if this is possible, but I would like to fill in a column based on an adjacent column in a SQL Server table.

As below, we would like to dynamically determine the `BillingDealerPeriodID` by using the **6th** and **7th** and the **3rd** and **4th characters** from `BillingDateTo`.

I am not sure if it matters, but `BillingDateTo` is also a computed column based on another column `BillingDateFrom`, which is 7 days from `BillingDateFrom`.

The formula for the `BillingDateTo` computed column is:

```
(dateadd(day,(7),[BillingDateFrom]))
```

If the result had to be 2102 or 2103 instead of 0221 and 0321, that would be fine too.

> | BillingDateTo | BillingDealerPeriodID |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2021-02-28 00:00:00.000 | 0221 |
> | 2021-03-07 00:00:00.000 | 0321 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will produce `YYMM`, like `2102`, `2103`, etc.:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(4), GETDATE(), 12);
```

So we can add that to the existing computed column formula. Since `BillingDateTo` is a computed column, you can't nest those; you have to repeat the computed column expression for `BillingDateFrom` or, instead of using multiple computed columns, just expose these additional calculations in a view.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.whatever ADD BillingDealerPeriodID 
  AS (CONVERT(char(4), DATEADD(DAY, 7, BillingDateFrom), 12));
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f67caca49d821ce89cdb16a381f2b529)

If you really want `MMYY` instead of `YYMM`, you can do:

```
SELECT STUFF(CONVERT(char(10), GETDATE(), 110),3,6,'');
```

So as a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.whatever ADD BillingDealerPeriodID 
  AS STUFF(CONVERT(char(10), DATEADD(DAY, 7, BillingDateFrom), 110),3,6,'');
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ec55b5a60a7a4efa06c36766b602b43)

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql) doesn't do a great job of explicitly stating that computed columns can't be nested, other than the following:

> The expression can be a noncomputed column name

But the error message that results if you try is pretty explicit.

As an aside, I strongly recommend staying away from variations that use `FORMAT()` - while it's convenient, intuitive, and better matches capabilities in other more sophisticated languages, it is [unacceptably slow](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but) (and also doesn't work in off-shoots like Azure SQL Edge).

Answer (score 1):

One can't create a computed column based on another computed column.

So you'll have to base it on a real column like BillingDateFrom

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.your_table
 ADD BillingDealerPeriodID
  AS (FORMAT(dateadd(day,7,[BillingDateFrom]), 'MMyy'));
```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=99db4a08f984d80929f06f446ed702c9)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXTRACT()` and `FORMAT()`. For example:

```
select format(datepart(month, BillingDateTo), '0#') +
       format(datepart(year, BillingDateTo) - 2000, '0#')
from t
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
----------------
0221
0321
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9e9573a1ff5d44e119cff849428a8c6c).